# How to store split into an array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to store the values that I splitted in an array. I've tried printing it outside of the for loop but it just gives me a single value.

```
Date            Close/Last     Volume        Open          High           Low
10/06/2021      $142           83221120      $139.47       $142.15        $138.37
```

```
def stocks(file) :
    try:
        fh = open(file, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("error opening file ....", file)
    else:
        arr = {}
        records = fh.readlines()
        for record in records:
            fields = record.split(',')
            arr = fields[2]
        print(arr)
        fh.close()
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the input file?

Comment: `arr` is a `dict`. What is `arr = fields[2]` supposed to do? Did you mean `arr[fields[2]] = fields`? (Also, you probably want to have a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.)

Comment: You'll need to append it to the array using the `list.append()` method.

Comment: There are no arrays in this code. Now that you've edited the question to show sample data I suggest you refer to the *csv* module as that is what your data appears to be

Comment: @PaulinaKhew I have added an example for the input file. The index is supposed to be Volume and I am trying to store its values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` function is doing what you're expecting it to do. However, in the `for` loop, you're creating this new variable `arr` that you're assigning to `fields[2]`. I'm assuming you want to *append* this value to the array. Also,

```
arr = {}
```

initializes a dictionary and not an array. With these changes, your code is as follows:

```
def stocks(file) :
    try:
        fh = open(file, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("error opening file ....", file)
    else:
        arr = []
        records = fh.readlines()
        for record in records:
            fields = record.split(',')
            arr.append(fields[2])
        print(arr)
        fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a list of values in the Volume column of a CSV file.

If you prefer not to import *csv* then you could do this:

```
def stocks(file):
    try:
        with open(file) as fh:
            arr = []
            next(fh) # skip column names
            for line in fh:
                if len(tokens := line.split()) >= 3:
                    arr.append(tokens[2])
            return arr
    except Exception:
        print(f'Failed to open {file}')
```